# How do I get a "Distraction" medal?

Tags: halo-4

The text says:

> Distract an opponent who is then killed.

What counts as "distraction"?  It seems like if I merely damage them and someone else kills them that would be interpreted as an "assist".  On a related note, can I get a "Distract" medal when I do the killing, or only when I assist allies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to obtain the Distraction Medal
[image]

You need to have been shot at by an enemy, then a teammate needs to kill said enemy.
I have gotten it by shooting back at the enemy then running, and also without doing any damage to the enemy whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, you get a **Distraction** medal when an opponent is concentrating fire on you when someone else kills that opponent.

Comment: +1 For correctness - gave the check to hammy for having a little more detail.

Answer (score 0):

my personal experience with this is the distraction medal is awarded to a decoy. when you are seen by the enemy and they open fire on you (you don't need to take damage) and your teammate kills them while they are paying attention to you, you are then awarded the distraction medal.